# Как вывести значения `SeekBar` в `TextView`

Tags: android, аудио, mediaplayer

У меня работает audio `SeekBar`. Я хочу, чтобы `TextView` (timeAudio) показал оставшееся время или продолжительность трека

```
private void initViews() {

        tb_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tb_title);
        timeAudio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeAudio);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    int position, long id)   {
                playSong(position);
                tb_title.setText(listContent[position]);


                            }
        });

    }


    private void seekChange(View v){
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
            mp.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
        }
    }

    public void play (View view) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
        } else {
            mp.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop (View view) {
        mp.stop();
    }

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {
// Play song
        mp.reset();// stops any current playing song
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID[songIndex]);
        mp.start();

        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mSeekBar);
        mSeekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser && mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }


        });



        startPlayProgressUpdater();
    }


    public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());

        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }else{
            mp.pause();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }

}
```

Comment: Делайте заголовки вопросов более лаконичными и краткими, выражающими только общую суть проблемы. Подробности и требующие решения задачи, а тем более имена переменных описывайте в самом вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Для отображения текста используется метод `TextView.setText`. Везде, где Вы обновляете позицию `SeekBar` с помощью `seekTo` делайте так же `timeAudio.setText`.

Единственная загвоздка в том, что в андроиде нет простого метода для красивого отображения времени в миллисекундах в удобно читаемом виде. Если длительность композиции гарантированно не больше суток, то можно воспользоваться следующим способом:

```
SimpleDateFormat durationFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

private void displayTime(long timeInMillis) {
    timeAudio.setText(durationFormat.format(new Date(timeInMillis)));
}
```